SwiftUI ForEach of protocols results in "requirement that 'Content' conform to 'AccessibilityRotorContent'"
I'm looking at iterating over an array of protocols and get them each to render a view. The protocol has a buildView function that returns any View, but calling this inside my view has the error:

Static method 'buildExpression' requires that 'Content' conform to 'AccessibilityRotorContent

Here's the code below, I don't really know what's going on and would greatly appreciate some help in debugging it.
import UIKit
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

protocol ViewItem: AnyObject, Hashable, Identifiable {
    var id: UUID { get }
    func buildView() -> any View
}

class ViewOne: ViewItem {
 
    let id: UUID = UUID()
    
    func buildView() -> any View {
        Text("View one")
    }
    
    static func == (lhs: ViewOne, rhs: ViewOne) -> Bool {
        lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
    
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(id)
    }
    
}

class ViewTwo: ViewItem {
    
    let id: UUID = UUID()
    
    func buildView() -> any View {
        Text("View two")
    }
    
    static func == (lhs: ViewTwo, rhs: ViewTwo) -> Bool {
        lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
    
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(id)
    }
    
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    let viewItems: [any ViewItem]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(viewItems, id: \.id) { viewItem in
                viewItem.buildView() <------------------ ERROR HERE
            }
        }
    }
}




func buildView() -> any View

The code above is not allowed within body, with or without ForEach.
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        createAnyView()  // ❌
        createSomeView() // ✅
    }
}

func createAnyView() -> any View {
    Text("any view")
}

func createSomeView() -> some View {
    Text("some view")
}

AFAIK, the body must contain some View or a type-erased AnyView. So, an approach is changing your protocol function to:
protocol ViewItem {
    ...
    func buildView() -> AnyView
}

class ViewOne: ViewItem {
    func buildView() -> AnyView {
        AnyView(
            Text("View one")
        )
    }
}

However, it has drawbacks such as unpredictable view state, animation, performance, etc... since SwiftUI doesn't even know what View it will be to optimize when it needs to re-render. You can check this out Demystify SwiftUI performance.

Thus, if I were you, I would go with some View solution:
protocol ViewItem {
    ...
    associatedtype ContentView: View
    func buildView() -> ContentView
}

Then I will wrap each type into a kind of builder, because passing directly ViewItem into a View will force the input param to any as mentioned in SE-0335.
enum Content: View, Identifiable {
    case viewOne(ViewOne)
    case viewTwo(ViewTwo)

    var body: some View {
        switch self {
        case .viewOne(let viewOne):
            viewOne.buildView()
        case .viewTwo(let viewTwo):
            viewTwo.buildView()
        }
    }

    var id: ObjectIdentifier {
        switch self {
        case .viewOne(let viewOne):
            return viewOne.id
        case .viewTwo(let viewTwo):
            return viewTwo.id
        }
    }
}

Finally, implement ContentView as normal:
struct ContentView: View {

    var items: [Content]

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(items) { item in
                item.body
            }
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView(items: [
        .viewOne(.init()),
        .viewTwo(.init())
    ])
}

Side note: If you have several return statements in each ViewItem, you might consider adding @ViewBuilder to your protocol to use the power of function builder.
